# Why is the Windows Clipboard Returning No Formats When It Seems To Contain Data?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, clipboard

Why is the Windows Clipboard Returning No Formats When It Seems To Contain Data?

I'm unclear on how the Windows 10 Clipboard is working. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.   In C#, under WPF I'm using System.Windows.Clipboard.   I used Ctrl-C (^C) to copy and Ctrl-V (^V) to paste.    Here is the issue, usually when I do a ^C  to copy to the clipboard I can get the number of formats with the following code:

```
IDataObject ido = System.Window.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
string[] formats = ido.GetFormats();
int numberOfFormats = formats.length;
```

This usually works and with the formats extracted I can get the data out, but I'm finding that in some cases the number of formats returned is zero even though something is in the clipboard.

What I'm doing is running an application where I can run ^C, ^V to copy and paste data, but  when I test for clipboard contents there are no formats.   (Specifically it's Android Studio's Design view, and I'm copying and pasting visual components, but I have to handle any similar application, not just Android Studio.)

I know there is something in the clipboard because of this test:

```
1> I run a test where I ^C selected text in the application Notepad
to the clipboard. So it has contents.

2> I then ^C in Android Studio for the Design View, and ^V where it
properly pastes.

3> When I do a ^V in notepad, there is no text, which shows me that
contents of the clipboard were altered, meaning there is data in
there.
```

So, **why is it returning that there are no formats?**  Is there a way to get the data out of the clipboard?   As I pointed out above, I can get it out when the format is listed and extracted by GetFormat(), but when it returns zero formats I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for any feedback!

...John

Comment: You can use [inside clipboard](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html) to see the contents at all times.

Comment: @user8934733 -- Thanks.  I used the tool and it shows the clipboard to be empty.  So, for some reason it is deleting the clipboard contents, but not saving data to it.  Strange.  Copy and Paste work in the application as you'd expect.  Also, I notice that for copying xml text in Android Studio data does end up in the clipboard.

Comment: Are you sure that Android Studio uses the clipboard for copy/paste of visual design elements? It doesn't have to, and many programs like that don't.

Comment: *"an application where I can run ^C, ^V to copy and paste data"* - See, that's the issue. An application can handle keyboard shortcuts any way it wants. The application you're interacting with apparently doesn't use the clipboard to implement its internal copy-paste operation.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield -- I realize now that Android Studio uses the clipboard in some cases and not in other cases, but it does empty the clipboard every time.

Comment: @IInspectable - Yes, I've found that to be the case.  Blender 3D uses its own internal memory location.